# Switch on bitwise enumeration

Tags: powershell

I have an function that fetches data, validates it against a set of user specified parameters and outputs if it is correct or not and based on that takes action, and it works just fine. As a further development of the function I've tried to move to a bitwise enumeration for the 'flags' but cannot get it to work like i want.

I want to switch through the enumeration and run the case for all possible 'matches' but i only get matches on the case when there is only a direct match on the value. Ie. when the value is 1 it runs the case 'Milk' but if the value is 3 it will not run the 'Milk' and the 'Bread' case ... i kinda assume its trying to run the 'Milk, Bread' case.

Is there any easy way that I've failed to see around this? ><

```
[Flags()] enum Breakfast {

    Nothing = 0
    Milk = 1
    Bread = 2
    Egg = 4
    Bacon = 8
}

$BreakfastFlag = 3


Switch ([Breakfast]$BreakfastFlag){

    Nothing {
    Write-Host "No breakfast was selected" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
    } 

    Milk {
    Write-Host "Milk was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

    Bread {
    Write-Host "Bread was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

    Egg {
    Write-Host "Egg was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

    Bacon {
    Write-Host "Bacon was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a series of comparisons like `if ($BreakfastFlag -band [Breakfast]::Milk) { ... }`

Comment: I would've liked to solve it in an other way if possible. I basically have a lot of if statements in the function today and in the end it could easily end up in a code state i do not desire... :|

Comment: @Jonas, did you try it? It's not any longer than the switch statement with the added bonus that it does what you need. *(no else if's mind you, only if statements)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, Yes, I tried and ofc. it works and is a solution to the 'problem' i having. I was just after an cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: @Jonas - you could dynamically loop over all values in the enumeration, get it's name as a string and derive your end result from that but I wouldn't call that cleaner, just more complex. It would require no new if statement when an item get's added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yet another variant:

```
[Flags()] enum Breakfast {
    Nothing = 0
    Milk = 1
    Bread = 2
    Egg = 4
    Bacon = 8
}

$BreakfastFlag = 3

Switch ([Breakfast]$BreakfastFlag)
{
    Nothing {
        Write-Host "No breakfast was selected" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
    }

    { $_ -band [Breakfast]::Milk } {
        Write-Host "Milk was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

    { $_ -band [Breakfast]::Bread } {
        Write-Host "Bread was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

    { $_ -band [Breakfast]::Egg } {
        Write-Host "Egg was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }

    { $_ -band [Breakfast]::Bacon } {
        Write-Host "Bacon was selected!" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Milk was selected!
Bread was selected!
>> Script Ended
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 3):

If brevity is the goal, make an auxiliary function that accepts a hashtable with keys as text names of the flags and values as anything, including a scriptblock:

```
function Switch-Flag($value, [hashtable]$switchboard) {
    $type = $value.GetType()
    $intValue = $value.value__
    $parsed = New-Object $type
    foreach ($e in $switchboard.GetEnumerator()) {
        $key = $e.name
        if ($key -is $type) {
            $r = $key.value__
        } elseif ($key -is [int]) {
            $r = $key
        } elseif ($type::TryParse($key, [ref]$parsed)) {
            $r = $parsed.value__
        } else {
            continue
        }
        if (($intValue -band $r) -eq $r) {
            if ($e.value -is [ScriptBlock]) {
                $e.value.Invoke()
            } else {
                $e.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example 1, simplified:

```
[Breakfast]$flag = 3
Switch-Flag $flag @{
    Milk =  { Write-Host liquid }
    Bread = { Write-Host crunchy }
}
```

Usage example 2, ensuring the order of choices:

```
$flag = 3
Switch-Flag ([Breakfast]$flag) ([ordered]@{
    Milk =  'liquid'
    Bread = 'crunchy'
})
```

Usage example 3, using enum as keys:

```
[Breakfast]$flag = 3
Switch-Flag $flag @{
    ([Breakfast]::Milk) =  { $milk++ }
    ([Breakfast]::Bread) = { $bread++ }
}
```

P.S. This is 10 times slower than using `-band` expressions shown in the other answer (180 microseconds vs 18 microseconds) because apparently PowerShell is smart enough to [cache the expressions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7cea2914753a735a45cd7bdd40081b718d4c7aca/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Binding/Binders.cs#L1505) and it also runs the expression scriptblocks in local scope, that is, if I understand correctly, it doesn't create a new scope in case of switch expressions.

Comment: Nice. This is something i think i will have use of further on. Went with the solution @AntonKruglov provided for now.

Comment: @wOxxOm - when does a new execution context gets created? I find very little of value about execution contexts.

Comment: @wOxxOm - you write that *each {...}* creates a new execution context. Your code only creates one execution context but it's still littered with `{...}` pairs. I tried researching when a new execution context gets created. I can't find any rules about it and I know next to nothing about it *(eager enough to learn though)*

Comment: ScriptBlock is what creates a new scope and a new execution context, not simply { } which also denotes group of statements. When `{ ... }` is used for `switch` value selectors, each one is a ScriptBlock.

Comment: This *When { ... } is used for switch value selectors, each one is a ScriptBlock* was what I was missing, thank you. It's one of those things something just has to know then. There's no visual difference between a pair of brackets in an `if` statement or a `switch` statement. I doubt many people would know the performance implications.

Comment: Indeed, one has to remember that. Non-scope braces `{}` are only those for statements like `if`, `else`, `elseif`, `do`, `while`, `foreach` statement (not cmdlet alias).

Comment: @wOxxOm Indeed your solution is more versatile, upvoted. It may be of interest to actually profile speed and memory usage of your variant vs mine.

Comment: Yours is 10 times faster O_O. Apparently, PowerShell is smart enough to [cache the expressions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7cea2914753a735a45cd7bdd40081b718d4c7aca/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Binding/Binders.cs#L1505). And it also runs this scriptblock in local scope, that is, if I understand correctly, it doesn't create a new scope in case of `switch` expressions.